# Modifying current reg-ex to allow special characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, special-characters

I have this reg-ex to validate comma separated values:

```
regex = "/^[-\w\s]+(?:,[-\w\s]+)*$/"
```

Currently there are no special characters allowed.
What modification to this can be made to allow special characters in each comma separated value?

Comment: Could you define what "special" characters your are referring to?

Comment: @Olian04 all of them

Comment: This question is Unclear because we don't know what "special characters" means in this context.  The [mcve] is incomplete/unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add wanted special characters inside the character class like, for example:

```
/^[-\w\s#|@%]+(?:,[-\w\s#|@%]+)*$/
//      ^^^^            ^^^^
```

You can add any character you want.

Answer (score 0):

@Harman,

I cannot suggest edits in your regex, but I have one regex which I used sometime back in my code to incorporate special characters too.

Try this one:

`(?:^|,\s{0,})(["]?)\s{0,}((?:.|\n|\r)*?)\1(?=[,]\s{0,}|$)`

You can try this regex [here](https://regex101.com/)

Hope this will be helpful for you!